# ASP.Net GridView and TemplateField visibility - false but ItemTemplate still executing

Tags: asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

I inherited some crazy code from someone who's long gone.  He implemented a single custom control to implement a large passel of loosely related queries.

The control has a bunch of different panels, all set to Visible='false' to reflect the different set of filter inputs.  Then there's a single GridView for the results.  The GridView has `<asp:TemplateFields Visible='false'>` for the superset of all possible columns returned from all the different queries he wanted to run.

The code-behind for the control runs around at init flipping Visible='true' for the filter panel and the columns of the particular query wanted at the moment.

To compound the craziness, I just noticed that having `<asp:TemplateField Visible="false">` doesn't stop the <ItemTemplate> inside from getting built, so his control is doing all kinds of extra work that will never get seen.

To give one example:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Expiration Date" SortExpression="ExpirationDate" Visible="false"><br />
      <itemtemplate><br />
          <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="FormLink" Target="_blank" NavigateURL="<%# CreateFormLink() %>" Text='<%# DateUtil.getFormattedDate(Eval("ExpireDate")) %>' ><br />                
          </asp:HyperLink><br />
      </itemtemplate><br />
 </asp:TemplateField><br />
```

The code-behind method `CreateFormLink()` gets called even though Visible is false...

The only reason it hadn't blown up before was that the method uses StringBuilder to cobble together the href, and `StringBuilder.Append(Eval("foo"))` doesn't blow up.

I tried to replace the StringBuilder use with concatenations to be more memory efficient and got a boom when the column wasn't in the current result set.

Since `Visible='false'` isn't stopping the work from being done (even though it stops the display), is there a more canonical way to do this?  Or should I just start over?

Comment: You almost made a book here which made it difficult to understand your exact question. You need to be specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to implement show/hide logic in [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound.aspx) event.

If you do so, you have full control over calling of `CreateFormLink()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...  I implemented a variant; in the GridView OnInit() function where it was fiddling Visible, I added a bit at the end to go ahead and remove the columns that were left Visible=false from the GridView.Columns collection.